# Alternative to for-loops

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

Consider the following sample data:

```
mapmatrix <- cbind(c(1,2,3,4,5,6),c(1,2,4,5,7,10))
arrayA <- c(1,2,4,7,10)
arrayB = rep(0,length(arrayA))
for(i in 1:length(arrayB))
{
arrayB[i] = which(mapmatrix[,2]==arrayA[i])
}
```

I have been told to avoid for-loops in R as far as possible. I did find it very time consuming even when `arrayA` had about 400K elements, and `mapmatrix` was of dimension {2 million x 2}. Would appreciate if I can replace the `for`-loop with a faster alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
 match(arrayA, mapmatrix[,2])
 #[1] 1 2 3 5 6
```

If you have repeated matches, `fmatch` from `library(fastmatch)` would be faster

```
  library(fastmatch)
  fmatch(arrayA, mapmatrix[,2])
  #[1] 1 2 3 5 6
```